# Rails: Find tasks that were created on a certain day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of tasks (name, starts_at) and I'm trying to display them in a daily view (just like iCal).

```
def todays_tasks(day)
    Task.find(:all, :conditions => ["starts_at between ? and ?", day.beginning, day.ending]
end
```

I can't figure out how to convert Time.now such as "2009-04-12 10:00:00" into the beginning (and end) of the day dynamically so I can make the comparison.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def todays_tasks(now = Time.now)
  Task.find(:all, :conditions => ["starts_at > ? AND < ?", now.at_beginning_of_day, now.at_end_of_day])
end
```

Voila!

Comment: Hello @august, I see at_end_of_day is breaking, so I used just end_of_day

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on augustl's answer a little bit. In your `Task` model you could define a method to fetch these tasks for you.

```
  def self.todays_tasks(t = Time.now)
    Task.all(:conditions => ["created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", t.at_beginning_of_day, t.tomorrow.at_beginning_of_day])
  end
```

This helps keep your controller skinny. I also compare the end of the day to the beginning of tomorrow. This makes sure that if a user creates a task at 11:59:59 PM it remains in the correct day.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```
Task.all(:conditions => ["created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?", Time.now.at_beginning_of_day, Time.now.tomorrow.at_beginning_of_day] )
```

Or else you would never check for 00:00:00 on the day of the tasks and 11:59:59 is the last value at the end of the day of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def todays_tasks(day)
   Task.where(:created_at => day.beginning_of_day .. day.end_of_day)
end
```