# Find all records that were created on a specific day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to find all records that were created on a specific day of week.
I only have available to me the standard model datetime timestamps.
How would I go about doing this in activerecord?

Comment: Rails 2 or 3? 
Do you mean a specific day e.g. 24.11.2010 or just "Thursday" as the day of week?

Comment: Related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742277/rails-find-tasks-that-were-created-on-a-certain-day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DAYOFWEEK function in MySQL and pass it to the :conditions option.  Supposing you have a model called Item, this would return all of the items created on Sunday:

> Item.all(:conditions => ['dayofweek(created_at) = ?', 1])

Using Postgres you could do something similar with [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-formatting.html).

Note that using a function like this will probably make the database do a full table scan, since at least MySQL doesn't support adding an index to a function.  You may want to consider extracting the day of week out to another column if this is something that you anticipate doing frequently.

Comment: the issue with `dayofweek` is that it will go based on UTC time. If you are using another timezone in your app there is a potential of mismatching. Not use the LOE to change mysql timezone or if thats even a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

To follow up on Justin's answer

```
where("extract(dow from created_at) = ?", Date.today.wday)
```

This is what I'm using in my application for postgres. This will find all records that were created on the same day-of-week as today. For example, if today was tuesday it would find all records created on tuesdays.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the seconds since Unix Epoch. `Time.to_i` does this in Ruby.

Use modulus of 7 to obtain the day of the week (0 to 6).

```
dayOfWeek = (epochseconds / 86400 ) % 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using ruby you could try this.

```
array.select { |arr| ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"].include?(arr.created_at.strftime('%A'))
```

I originally tried using `dayofweek` that was suggested in another answer.
The issue I ran in to was that it seems like my sql server was using UTC time and my rails server was using Eastern US. Records created after 8pm would be picked up while those that happened before would be considered the previous day.

Here is another related question:
[How to filter by day of week in Rails 4.2 and sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475018/how-to-filter-by-day-of-week-in-rails-4-2-and-sqlite)