# How to filter by day of week in Rails 4.2 and sqlite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

How to retrieve records by each day of week ?

This my scope:

```
scope :day_of_week, ->(day_of_week) { where("created_at = ?", day_of_week ) }
```

I 've tried strftime('%w', day_of_week) and DAYOFWEEK() without success.

I am using months and years without a problem and I am counting everything on my view. I am counting also items per day of week and even If I am not getting a syntax error, I am receiving 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
date = DateTime.now
#=> Mon, 06 Apr 2015 20:02:00 +0200
date.strftime('%A')
#=> "Monday"
```

So you have to check, if `created_at.strftime('%A')` equals to the `day_of_week` you are interested in.

Comment: It should work if scope :day_of_week, ->(day_of_week) { where("created_at = ?", "Monday" ) }, right?

Comment: nope, in your scope you are checking equality with `datetime` object, not string.

Comment: Makes sense... Do you think there's a way to merge it to one sentence? scope :day_of_week, ->(day_of_week) { where(created_at.strftime('%A'), day_of_week ) } ?

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: mytable.the_day_of_week: SELECT * FROM "mytable" WHERE (user_id = 1) AND "mytable"."the_day_of_week" = 'Monday'

Answer (score 2):

```
scope :day_of_week, ->(day_of_week) { where("strftime('%w', created_at) = ?", day_of_week.to_s) }
```

is the solution. I am not quite sure why `.to_s` worked but it seems that the documentation is not clear. If we consider that strftime means "String to Time type" then it should need a string.

Answer (score 1):

If someone got stuck with it, answer from [Radolino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1576116/radolino) is working, but `'%w'` returns you id of day of week like this:

```
Sunday: 0, Monday: 1, Tuesday: 2, Wednesday: 3, Thursday: 4, Friday: 5, Saturday: 6
```

But rails method `Date::DAYS_INTO_WEEK` gives you this id's:

```
Sunday: 6, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 1, Wednesday: 2, Thursday: 3, Friday: 4, Saturday: 5
```

So you need to check your `params` before filtering.